# when a node down, how to remove all datas that put from this node?

Tags: hazelcast

I use hazelcast to store the user connections for a push service, if a node down, connections for this node will lost, and I want all datas related to those connections will also be removed from hazelcast. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running a periodic task on other nodes and using a key or value struct giving you information who created that entry. If the node is not available in the Cluster::getMembers list anymore others can remove those entries.